# How can I get the sum for values in a dictionary in swift?

Tags: swift

dictionary:[String:Double] = [:]

dictionary = ["07/03/21": 331, "08/03/21": 854, "09/03/21": -80]

how can I add the values of the dictionary?
sum = 331 + 854 + -80 <- like this in swift.

Comment: `let sum = dictionary.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```objectivec
var dictionary:[String:Double] = [:]

dictionary = ["07/03/21": 331, "08/03/21": 854, "09/03/21": -80]
let sum = dictionary.compactMap {$0.value}.reduce(0, +)
print(sum)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not simply `let sum = dictionary.reduce(0) { $0 + $1.value }`? Btw Swift 5.2 or later you can use keyPath `compactMap(\.value)`